# How to put some text in the drawer navigation react native

Tags: react-native

This is my drawer navigation :

```
const MainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    Home : HomeStackNav,
    About : AboutStackNav
},
{
    contentOptions: {
        activeTintColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'white' : Colors.primaryColor,
        inactiveTintColor: 'black',
        
        activeBackgroundColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? Colors.primaryColor : '',
        inactiveBackgroundColor: Colors.white
    }
}
);
```

I want in the footer of my drawer navigation to text something for example: made with love...

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this react-navigation 4?

on version 5 it will be:

```
    function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>made with love</View>
      </View>
  );
}

<Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}> ......</Drawer.Navigator>
```

i think on  react-navigation 4

```
{
 .....
contentComponent: (props) => {

   return <CustomDrawerContent {...props} /> 
},
.....
```